# String in hebrew not work in preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all, hebrew

```
<?php

$badWords = array("ban","bad","user","pass","stack","name","html");

$string = "Hello my name is user.";

$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
                $string, 
                $matches
              );

if ($matchFound) {
  $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
  foreach($words as $word) {
    echo "<li>" . $word . "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

but when I change $badWords to Hebrew:

```
$badWords = array("עזה","חמאס");
```

and change the text ($string) to Hebrew:

```
$string = "חמאס רוצה להרוג אותנו ולא יצליח";
```

It doesn't work.

Why?

It works fine in English!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to inform the regex engine that the pattern your are working with contains utf-8 characters, and you have to change the meaning of the character class `\w` and of the word boundaries `\b` to deal with utf-8 character *(since by default `\w` contains only ascii letters)*. To do that you have two ways:

using the u modifier:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
            "/\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/iu", 
            $string, 
            $matches
          );
```

or putting `(*UTF8)(*UCP)` at the very start of the pattern:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
            "/(*UTF8)(*UCP)\b(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")\b/i", 
            $string, 
            $matches
          );
```

`(*UTF8)` informs the regex engine that the pattern string must be seen as an utf8 string.

`(*UCP)` changes `\w` that is by default `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`

Comment: @user3850393: Change all your setting to utf8, save your php file and set your code editor to utf8, configure you server, your database to utf8. If you import datas from an other source convert it to utf8. Otherwise you will experience a nightmare.

Comment: its show me error: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 3

Comment: @user3850393: try to use `mb_convert_encoding`.